# Why my point does not move in the direction specified by quaternion?

Tags: vectors, quaternions

I have a quaternion **q** and want to obtain 3 points **f, a, b** where **f** (forward) is at the *r* distance in the direction pointed by the quaternion and **a, b** are at the *r* distance in both other two directions, prependicular to the direction pointed by the quaternion. For this, I create the unit vectors pointing in the needed direction, multiply it by the quaternion and then multiply by the distance required, and expect my points to be:

- **f** = **p** + [1,0,0,0] * **q** * *r*
- **a** = **p** + [0,1,0,0] * **q** * *r*
- **b** =  **p** + [0,0,1,0] * **q** * *r*

This works well in majority of cases but time to time it ... just does not. Why does it sometimes works and sometimes not? I tried to set the 4th member of the vector also to 1, this sometimes helps but the I get other, different points incorrect. What I am doing wrong? To multiply a vector by the quaternion that has four components, it must be the four member vector. Should I also use the 4th component of my transation vector? If so, how?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to find a nice way of, given one vector, finding two perpendicular vectors in three dimensions? Unfortunately, due to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem there isn't a nice way of doing this. You'll have to accept some amount of discontinuity where the perpendicular vectors you calculate suddenly switch.

Comment: Not a solution but explains why I cannot just Google out the answer. Looking for work around.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the quaternion, use rotation matrix:

- **f** = **p** + [1,0,0] * **m** * *r*
- **a** = **p** + [0,1,0] * **m** * *r*
- **b** =  **p** + [0,0,1] * **m** * *r*

where **m** is a 3x3 rotation matrix (the vectors now only have 3 elements). The solution seems much more stable with the rotation matrix.

Of course, for some this may raise another problem how to [convert quaternion to rotation matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1556260/convert-quaternion-rotation-to-rotation-matrix), but in my case it was possible to obtain the rotation matrix directly.